# Add a Pan Gesture Recognizer to an UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

How can I add a Pan Gesture Recognizer to an UITableView, without blocking my scrolling feature of my TableView?

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var ScanPanGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!

@IBAction func ScanPanGestureRecognizer(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("TEST")
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    ScanTableView.addGestureRecognizer(ScanPanGestureRecognizer)
}
```

So the code works and I get a lot of prints with "Test" but I'm not able to move (scroll) my TableView any more. I have read some other questions / answers but I couldn't find my issue. I thought that the extension "addGestureRecognizer" only add a gesture and not overwrite the TableView pan gesture... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think whatever you want to do with a pan gesture recognizer on a `UITableView` you can do it in `UITableView`'s delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll:` in that method the `scrollView.contentOffset` will tell you how much the tableView has scrolled

Comment: Good answer! But what do I have to set for contentOffset? I tried content offset.y >= 2 but that doesn't work..

Comment: what do you mean by "have to set for contentOffset"

Comment: Ahhh okay... I got it! I tried to compare the ContentOffset.y value with a constant value, to decide if I have to do something or not. But I compared the value with positive values and not negativ ;) Soo thank you!

Comment: This does not account for the case of using a custom subview of a `UITableViewCell` that tracks horizontal pan gestures.